# Посмотреть участников чужого закрытого канала телеграм

Tags: telegram

В чате с 100+ участниками кто то анонимно присылает сообщения от лица своего канала. Спамит, кидает запрещенку и т.д. Канал закрытый, отчего видно количество участников, но нет никнеймов и аватарок. От этого найти нарушителя нереально, а банить методом тыка просто бессмысленно. Что же делать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Переходите в Одноклассники, там все прекрасно и прозрачно

Answer (score 0):

Стоит попытаться посмотреть айди канала (переслав сообщение нарушителя в лс этому боту: @getmyid_bot) и забанить канал в чате по нему, используя сторонних ботов по типу @GroupButler_bot или ему подобных.